# How to make a CCParticleExplosion non-repeating?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, particle-system

I'm using cocos2d-x and I can get a CCParticleExplosion firing mostly correctly, but I'm looking for a way to enable it to burst its particles just once and not repeat.  I can try to hack this together with duration/life settings, but I'd rather be able to specify this explicitly.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a BOOL property `autoRemoveOnFinish`. Set it to YES and it will remove one-shot particle effects like explosion when all particles have "died". A one-shot particle effect is one whose time is set to a positive value (ie not -1).